# Outlook replyall to appointmentitem

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I am writing a script to reply to AppointmentItem in outlook. The AppointmentItem does not expose ReplyAll (or Reply) method, and that is only available for MeetingItems. However, all the events on a user's calendar are stored as AppointmentItem class, even if there are multiple attendees. I am wondering how I can ReplyAll to an AppointmentItem? Is there any way to get the associated MeetingItem?

PS: When I right click on an AppointmentItem in Calendar it does enable ReplyAll, so there should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this API/feature is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.